# why doesn't following Python removing duplicates function work?

Tags: python

I am trying make a **remove duplicate** function in python but for some reason it gives strange output. note that I do wish to use `list(set(some_list))`. I just want to know why the following gives such output.

```
def removeD(A):
    for num in A:
        if A.count(num) > 1:
            A.remove(num)
    return A

A = [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2]
print (removeD(A))
```

outputs:

> [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]

Comment: Also see [Remove items from a list while iterating in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating-in-python).

Comment: @BhargavRao, I changed the dupe, the OP is asking more about why the code does not work as opposed to how to achieve the desired result

Comment: @Padraic. Thanks for that. :)